# Insert sound into an mp3 track

Tags: linux, bash, audio, mp3

I'm looking for a way to insert a custom sound at a given second into an MP3 track. I'd like to be able to do this without GUI tools so I can invoke it from a bash script, and I'd like this sound to be layered over the regular track.

The goal is to test if this would work with the pomodoro technique. I'd have a track which goes steady for 25 minutes, then an audio cue to take 5 and then another audio cue to start work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux you can easily convert to and from `wav`. `Mpg123` (or `mpg321`) can convert to `wav` adding the option `-w out.wav`. `Lame` is a popular example for the inverse: wav to mp3.

Editing the audio itself can, again, be done in many ways. One very capable audio editor is `snd` which is available [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/snd/snd.html).

Note: `snd` can even load, edit and save `mp3` files directly. I seem to remember having some problems though. Several newer versions have appeared, so that could have been solved.